# "Last backup could not be completed" when "Last backup: Never"

Tags: icloud, backup

I have deleted all major iCloud backups and removed Camera Roll etc. from the impending backup so it should be less than 5 GB. Even still, when I re-enable iCloud Backup and go to sync for the first time, I'm told that the "Last backup could not be completed". Tried power cycling and still no change. What gives?

Comment: Are you able to backup to your computer with a cable or is it just iCloud backups that don't work?

Comment: @fbara, just iCloud—manual computer backup is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the date of your post, you were using iOS 9 at the time. I experienced this issue myself with backups in iOS 9. Forcing another iCloud backup would eventually allow it to complete, but over time I had to deal with runaway backup sizes (growing up to upwards of 5 GiBs after a few days).

As far as I can tell, this appears to be resolved at last in iOS 10. I would recommend performing a backup in iTunes, then upgrading before trying another iCloud backup.

Comment: In iOS 10, I get "This iPhone cannot be backed up because there is not enough iCloud storage available" (free iCloud space: 4.9 GB, tentative "next backup size": 6 GB). I removed all apps > 40 MB and now the backup image is 4.8 GB, so it fits but barely. Still unclear what is taking up most of that 5 GB backup, though I imagine it's Messages.

Comment: Could be messages; on my phone my Health database was also very large, from using an Apple Watch and getting heart rate and step/distance measurements every few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common for iOS users to come across [the last backup could not be completed](http://www.iphonedata.net/how-to-fix-the-last-backup-could-not-completed-error-on-iphone.html) issue while backing up the iPhone or iPad to iCloud. The reasons are various but luckily, there are also various solutions:

Solution 1: Backup iPhone to computer via iTunes (Make sure you have a backup in case something goes wrong)

Solution 2: Log out off iCloud and Log back in (iCloud could be the primary cause, so check it out to see if you can fix it there)

Solution 3: Reset Network Settings (Your device might not be connected to network properly)

Solution 4: Change to New WiFi network (Check if there is something wrong with your network and try another network)

Solution 5: Delete old backup from iCloud (You have only 5 GB of free iCloud storage, and once the backup exceeds 5 GB, it won’t backup the iPhone)

Solution 6: Restore your iPhone (Restoring your iPhone will give you a brand-new, clean device from the start)